# For all $U\supset E$ there is a $V$ such that $E\subset U\subset V$.

Tags: general-topology

$(X,T)$ a topological space and $E\subset X$.

Is there a theorem that say that for all open $U\supset E$ with $U\neq E$, there exist an open $E\subset V\subset U$ with $E\neq V\neq U$ ?

Comment: This is not true: Take $X = \{1\}$, $E = \emptyset, U = \{1\}$.

Comment: And if $X=\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: Well, if $E$ differs from $U$ by just one point, then it is clearly not true. However, what you are looking for is perhaps normality. If $X$ is normal, and $E$ is *closed*, then you get what you want. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such theorem, because it's not always true.

Take $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $T = \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then $(X,T)$ is a topological space, and clearly, the only open set bigger than $\{1,2\}$ is $X$.

Comment: ok, and if $X$ is a metric space ?

Comment: @Rick You can have a discrete metric space. So that's not enough either.

Comment: @Rick specifically the space given by Tryss is metrizable.

Comment: And if $X=\mathbb R^n$ ? It's in fact in this case where I need it.

Comment: @rick that's still not true unless you know more about $E$. Take $E$ to be an open ball around the origin with the origin excluded and let $U$ be the same ball around the origin with the origin included. You can't separate those two with an open set.

Comment: Ok, then I have a set $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Why is there an open $Q\supset E$ such that $|Q|<|E|+\varepsilon$ ? It's in a course a Lebesgue-measure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29705/discussion-between-drf-and-rick).

Comment: @DRF and Rick: Since a metrizable space is normal, for all closed $F$ and all open $U\supset F$, there is an open $V$ such that $F\subset V\subset \bar V\subset  U$. Therefore, there is an open set $V$ such that $E\subset \bar E\subset V\subset U$.

Comment: @surb True. But where in the original do you see any restriction on $F$ or rather $E$ in OP's terminology? You can separate open and closed sets but not open and arbitrary sets. As the example with removing an internal point from an open ball shows. The closure of $E$ might no longer be contained in $U$ again see example with open ball and open ball with center removed. One more thing are you certain that you get strict inclusions? I ask because I'm wondering about discrete metric spaces (e.g. integers).

Comment: Well, the question is truly ambigus, but there is anyway an open that contain $\bar E$ and then, we can apply normal characterization. But you are right to mention that it doesn't work for all $U$. To answer to you question, inclusion are not strict.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you have a lot more then just a topological space. The trivial space is an easy counterexample. Any space which has open points will also break this, for example any discrete topology. In general if there is an open singleton you already can't get the result you want.

Edit: In response to some extra comments I would like to point out that there is no way I can think of specifying the topological space that would allow this to work. You would need extra conditions on $E$ as well. Even in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ this condition won't hold assuming we take $E$ to be an open ball around the origin with the origin removed and $U$ the same ball which includes the origin.

Comment: Ok, and if $X$ is a metric space ?

Comment: @rick see my comment under Tryss's answer.